# JBOSS_HOME not set, import project into IntelliJ fails

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jboss, wildfly

After attempting to import a project from gradle in IntelliJ 15 (mac, OSX El Capitan), I get a Resolve Error saying that "JBOSS_HOME" env property must be set and pointed at a valid Jboss installation".

I then...

- downloaded wildfly-10.0.0.CR5, which I believe is latest version of JBoss AS
- updated my bash_profile for JBOSS_HOME environment variable

  ```
  export JBOSS_HOME="/Users/JDoe/Projects/wildfly-10.0.0.CR5"
  ```
- updated IntelliJ preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Application Servers > Jboss 10.0.5.Final

It still fails. What other preferences or settings do I need to set in IntelliJ or elsewhere?

Comment: Note that 10.0.0.CR5, as the name indicates, is a Candidate Release version - the latest stable version is 9.0.2 (although that is unlikely to explain your problem).

Comment: if you manually add new application server configuration in settings --> application servers. Does that work?

Comment: @assylias in any case, it *is* latest avalibale version.

Comment: Where in Preferences is that? I already added it via Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Application Servers